# How to do nested filtering using handsontable in angularJS 2

Tags: angular, handsontable

Hi every one I am trying to build a nested search for using handsontable.
The motive after typing letter in search box when enter is pressed the table should render with the rows match with the search word, again if a second word in search box, the search should be done over the previous result.

Example :-
1. If there are 5 rows in the table default.
2. Type word hit enter rows become 3.
3. Next search rows become 2.

For the requirement i am maintaining a array of hidden rows and every enter key i am untrimAll() all the rows and then trimRows(hidden_rows).
Below is the code sample on hitting enter

```
enterpressed(list) {
    this.hidden_Row;
    this.trimRowPlugin.untrimAll();
    this.hot.render();
    // get_hidden rows array from a method
    this.trimRowPlugin.trimRows(this.hidden_Row);
    this.hot.render();
}
```

The problem is some times the rendered rows are getting empty.
[Some thing like](http://jsfiddle.net/n8ggsbob/13/)
Which i want to avoid.

Any help is appreciated.